# Is it possible to merge team members calendars in Office 365 Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, office365

In Office 365, I understand that users can use Sharepoint for sharing the team members calendars (as the below videos show).

My question is: is it possible that each team member could update / import their own calendar into this shared team calendar to make it as a merged calendar to provide the transparent information to the whole team?

Any suggestions or alternative approaches are appreciated... thanks.

**References**:

A team site calendar helps keep your team in sync by sharing everyone’s meetings, project milestones, and vacation time.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-create-a-shared-calendar-in-office-365-61b96006-70e2-4535-a34f-ee4fc772f798

Use Team/Group Calendar: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-group-calendar-7f559b2e-1f90-49b4-a0fe-2d235994945e